# Создание HashMap в методе

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как применить метод createMap() в main. Пробовал различные варианты, но никак не могу создать HashMap через метод. Ошибка при применении метода createMap() "HashMap m = createMap();"

```
public class Solution {
    public static HashMap<String, Date> createMap() throws ParseException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        HashMap<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date>();
        map.put("Stallone", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone1", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone2", df.parse("JULE 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone3", df.parse("AUGUST 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone4", df.parse("SEPTEMBER 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone5", df.parse("OCTOBER 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone6", df.parse("NOVEMBER 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone7", df.parse("DECEMBER 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone8", df.parse("JANUARY 1 1980"));
        map.put("Stallone9", df.parse("FEBRUARY 1 1980"));
        return map;
    }

    public static void removeAllSummerPeople(HashMap<String, Date> map) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,Date> m = createMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уверен, проблема не при запуске, а при компиляции, т.к. `createMap` может выбросить исключение, а автор его не ловит (и в его `main` не указано что то исключение может быть выброшено):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        HashMap<String, Date> m = createMap();
        System.out.println(m);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

**PS.**

После этой правки код скомпилируется, но будет исключение, т.к. формат даты не совпадает с тем, что парсится:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "JULE 1 1980"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

т.к. название месяца неправильно написано, должно быть `JULY`

Comment: Спасибо за указание на опечатку. Убрал все put-ы кроме одного         "map.put("Stallone", df.parse("JUNE 1 1980"));" В итоге код компилируется без ошибок, но на экран не выводится запись.

Comment: А как вывести на экран запись Stallone?

Comment: Попробуйте: `System.out.println(m.get("Stallone"));`

Comment: Пробовал. Так же, попробовал сделать вот так:               try {
            HashMap<String, Date> m = createMap();
            for (String s:m.keySet())
                System.out.println(m);
            System.out.println("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error");
        } в итоге пусто. Тоесть, ни надписи "test", ни 'error'. Такое чувство как будто все что написано в try или catch не выполняется

Comment: @SVI, `for (Map.Entry<String, Date> entry : m.entrySet()) { System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue()); }`

Comment: Все так же, пусто. Вот что у меня в данный момент получилось: https://wmpics.pics/di-G639.png

Comment: @SVI, не могу видеть фотку -- корпоративная прокси с белым списком. Если пусто, то возможно у вас словарь (Map) пустой. `System.out.println(m.size() + ": " + m);` если и это не дало результата, то добавьте в ваш вопрос текущий код или создайте новый вопрос по новой проблеме

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, добавляйте `@<ник>` чтобы обратиться к конкретному участнику, а то без указанного ника участник не увидит в уведомлениях ваш комментарий к нему

Comment: @gil9red а кому вы предлагали попробовать `m.get("Stallone")`?

Comment: @SVI Вы точно запускаете то что нужно? контрол+шифт+Ф10

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, SVI'у, пока в этой ветке комментариев он был один, то комментарии к нему адресовались, когда участников несколько, по-идеи, или все увидят (что сомневаюсь) или только родитель (тот, под чьим ответом или вопросом был оставлен комментарий). Например, когда вы написали без ника комментарий, его я увидел в уведомлениях :)

Comment: @gil9red тогда какая разница, если все увидят? И вообще, если увидят все, то и для себя извлекут пользу, если у них такая же проблема возникала когда-либо

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, не все хотят принудительно получать уведомления о том что кто-то где-то написал комментарий. И часто подобные комментарии скатываются в флуд, т.к. в комментах принято обсуждать по теме ответа/вопроса

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Действительно, я запускал не тот класс. Спасибо большое всем за ответы, особенно gil9red !

Comment: SVI, у вас формат даты в строке указан не верно, поэтому не парсится дата... попробуйте изменить на `map.put("Stallone", dateFormat.parse("06-01-1980"));` и тогда результат будет выведен в консоли

Comment: @SVI, рад что разобрались, а [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)